# CloudFlare 522 errors on some SE sites at the moment

Tags: bug, status-completed, offline, outage, cloudflare

The picture below says it all :)

Currently noticed on:

- StackOverflow
- Travel.SE
- Webmasters.SE

It's a little intermittent as well.

> Error 522
>   Ray ID: 2aef4188a0151d80
>   2016-06-06 22:21:27 UTC
>   Connection timed out

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are in the process of moving all our sites from Cloudflare over to Fastly and we also apparently got DDoS'd along the way. Fun for the whole family!

Comment: Youch. Good luck on the rest of the move!

Comment: Good move! From what I've seen CF gave you just trouble...