# Was the Stack Exchange network affected by the Cloudflare parser bug?

Tags: support, security, privacy, cloudflare

Cloudflare [disclosed a memory leak incident](https://blog.cloudflare.com/incident-report-on-memory-leak-caused-by-cloudflare-parser-bug/) in their software, which could lead to:

> returning memory that contained private information such as HTTP cookies, authentication tokens, HTTP POST bodies, and other sensitive data. And some of that data had been cached by search engines.

Is Stack Exchange affected by this bug, or [is the entire network migrated to Fastly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279998/245360) already? Couldn't find a definitely source about the latter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We were not directly affected.

The parser bug [was introduced](https://blog.cloudflare.com/incident-report-on-memory-leak-caused-by-cloudflare-parser-bug/#goingbughunting):

> The earliest date memory could have leaked is 2016-09-22

Stack Exchange went off CloudFlare around June 2016.

---

The caveat is that it is entirely possible that some services we use were compromised - after all, a large amount of the Internet goes through CloudFlare.